# Bind two or more domains for each language in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, multilingual

Hey! I got a slight problem with multilanguage site. Hope you guys can help me out!

I got multilanguage multi-domain website with shared code- and databases. 
Everything works fine as long as there is only one domain bound per language (for example domain.com => english, domain.de => german, domain.no => norway).

The problem is that I need to bind more than one domain for each language. For example domain.de, AND sub.domain.de, AND sub2.domain.de should be bound to german. 
However currently i18n only supports one domain per language.
So basically i can assign domain.de to german but not other domains/sub-domains.

So the question is that is there any way to bind two or more domains per language? I'm using domain access and i18n to handle all this. Or is the only solution to create custom languages for each domain?
Custom languages kinda feels stupid solution since no two identical languages are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Domain Locale](http://drupal.org/project/domain_locale) module? It allows you to specify, on a per-domain basis what languages are available, and which default language to use. The Domain Conf module (bundled with Domain Access) may also come in handy, as it allows the override of variables on a per-domain basis.

Answer (score 0):

Domain access is a pretty module through which we can be configured with single domain with multiple languages and even default language can be set.